# Problema con la probabilidad en Java

Tags: java, porcentaje

este es mi primer aporte a esta comunidad, aunque sea en forma de pregunta.

Estoy haciendo un programa que genera humanos con todas sus características, sexo, ojos, pelo, edad, nombre, apellidos, etc...
He creado una clase Ojos para generar el color de los ojos.
Resulta que cuando dos humanos se aparean, el humano resultante obtiene el color de los ojos en función del color de los ojos de sus padres.
He creado un array bididemsional con los diferentes casos:

```
private String[][] tablaOjos = {
       //Padre      Madre    marron  verde  azul
        {"Marron", "Marron", "75",   "18",  "7"},
        {"Verde",  "Marron", "50",   "37",  "13"},
        {"Azul",   "Marron", "49",   "2",   "49"},
        {"Verde",  "Verde",  "3",    "74",  "25"},
        {"Verde",  "Azul",   "2",    "49",  "49"},
        {"Azul",   "Azul",   "2",    "3",   "98"}

};
```

Las tres últimas posiciones corresponden al % de probabilidad de que se genere un color u otro.
He creado un método que recibe el color de los ojos de los padres, los compara con el array anterior(posiciones 0 y 1) y así obtengo los porcentajes que debo aplicar para obtener el color(posiciones 2,3 y 4).
El problema lo tengo a la hora de procesar dichos porcentajes.

Hasta ahora lo calculaba de esta manera:

```
public void generarColorOjos() {
    int numeroAleatorio = (int)(Math.random() * 100);

    if (numeroAleatorio <= 3) {
        this.colorOjos = "Heterocromía";
    }else if (numeroAleatorio <= 10) {
        this.colorOjos = "Verde";
    }else if (numeroAleatorio <= 14) {
        this.colorOjos = "Azul";
    }else if (numeroAleatorio > 14) {
        this.colorOjos = "Marrón";
    }
}
```

Este método me funciona cuando comparo los porcentajes de mayor a menor o viceversa. En el caso que expongo, los porcentajes no están en en ningún orden por lo que no puedo usar este método.

Os muestro el método que he creado:

```
public void generaColorOjosHijos(String colorOjosPadre, String colorOjosMadre) {
    int numeroAleatorio = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
    int verde = 0;
    int marron = 0;
    int azul = 0;
    int hetero = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < tablaOjos.length; i++) {
        if(tablaOjos[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(colorOjosPadre) && 
                (tablaOjos[i][1].equalsIgnoreCase(colorOjosMadre))) {
            marron = Integer.parseInt(tablaOjos[i][2]);
            verde = Integer.parseInt(tablaOjos[i][3]);
            azul = Integer.parseInt(tablaOjos[i][4]);
        }
    }

    if (numeroAleatorio <= hetero) {
        this.colorOjos = "Heterocromía";
    }else if (numeroAleatorio <= verde) {
        this.colorOjos = "Verde";
    }else if (numeroAleatorio <= azul) {
        this.colorOjos = "Azul";
    }else if (numeroAleatorio > marron) {
        this.colorOjos = "Marrón";
    }
}
```

Este método no funciona porque las variables verde, azul y marron obtienen valores diferentes según cada caso.
Se solucionaría creando tantos métodos como combinaciones de color existen pero no creo que sea una buena solución.

Después de esta chapa mi pregunta es: hay alguna otra manera de calcular y obtener probabilidades en java?

Comment: Tu pregunta es interesante, sin embargo no estás tomando en cuenta realmente el cálculo de probabilidades. La teoría puede ser bastante densa, pero todo va sobre el tipo de [Distribución de Probabilidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_de_probabilidad) que tengas en mente o que desees aplicar, en este caso tienes una tabla. Por lo que veo en tu código no hay mucho de eso al generar el número aleatorio. Puedes leer [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327958/random-number-with-probabilities) (en inglés) y así estarías un poco más cerca. Saludos

Comment: Creo que me equivoqué en la elección del título de mi consulta. Como bien dices, lo que yo pretendo es generar un número aleatorio. En el [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327958/random-number-with-probabilities) que compartiste he encontrado cosas muy interesantes. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo creo que cambiando un poco la tabla (aunque diría que está incompleta) y el último método lo puedes conseguir. A ver qué te parece esto:

```
private String[][] tablaOjos = {
   //Padre      Madre    marron  verde  azul
    {"Marron", "Marron", "75",   "93" }, // del 93 al 99
    {"Verde",  "Marron", "50",   "87" }, // ,etc.
    {"Azul",   "Marron", "49",   "51" },
    {"Verde",  "Verde",  "3",    "77" },
    {"Verde",  "Azul",   "2",    "51" },
    {"Azul",   "Azul",   "2",    "5" },
};
```

Fíjate que he sumado las probabilidades del color verde a las del marrón. Si cogemos el primer caso, todo lo que esté entre 1 y 75, será marrón, entre 76 y 93 verde, entre el 94 y el 99 azul. Dejamos el 100 para la heterocromía.

Para que funcione he hecho unos ligeros cambios en el método `generaColorOjosHijos()`:

```
   public void generaColorOjosHijos(String colorOjosPadre, String colorOjosMadre) {
            int numeroAleatorio = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
            int verde = 0;
            int marron = 0;
            int azul = 99; // desde el valor del verde hasta 99 siempre será azul
            int hetero = 100; // sólo un 1% para la heterocromía
            for (int i = 0; i < tablaOjos.length; i++) {
                if(tablaOjos[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(colorOjosPadre) && 
                        (tablaOjos[i][1].equalsIgnoreCase(colorOjosMadre))) {
                    marron = Integer.parseInt(tablaOjos[i][2]);
                    verde = Integer.parseInt(tablaOjos[i][3]);
                    //azul = Integer.parseInt(tablaOjos[i][4]); ya no hace falta
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (numeroAleatorio <= marron) {
                this.colorOjos = "Marrón";
            } else if (numeroAleatorio <= verde) {
                this.colorOjos = "Verde";
            } else if (numeroAleatorio <= azul) {
                this.colorOjos = "Azul";
            } else if (numeroAleatorio == hetero) {
                this.colorOjos = "Heterocromía";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tu solución me ha servido de mucho. A que te refieres cuando dices que la tabla está imcompleta?

Comment: Me daba la sensación de que estaba incompleta porque, por ejemplo, no contempla que haya un padre con ojos marrones y una madre con ojos verdes. Me alegro de que te haya servido.

Comment: Tienes razón. En realidad no importa si el padre tiene los ojos marrones o la madre los tiene verdes, lo que importa es la mezcla de colores de ambos. Modificaré el método para solucionar esto.
Se me ocurre asignarles un valor a los colores y, según el resultado de su suma, obtener el porcentaje a aplicar. De esta manera el array String[6][5] pasará a ser de tipo int[6][3] lo que me permitirá crear un método más claro y me ahorro unas cuantas lineas de código.